# Multiple foreign keys composing another element

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I am trying to create a database for some box listings. These boxes contain different products in various quantities. How should I implement the table which holds the content of each box?

I'm new to MySql and that is the reason why this may sound so as such a stupid question, but I don't understand how a table will hold different products and their quantities for each box.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because box and product would have a many to many relation, you can solve this by using a associative entity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity.

You have a table 'box', a table 'product' and a table 'box_product'

- Box has a one to many relation to box_product.
- Product also has a one to many relation to box_product

In box_product, you would have only 3 columns: 'id', 'box_id' and 'product_id'. 
(Could also be 2 columns if you use a composite primary key, and leave out 'id')

**Example:** 
Let's say one box has 3 products: A, B and C. It has one A, 2 B's and 3 C's.

For this example, there would be:

- one row in box
- 3 rows in product (you do not need to duplicate rows in the product table, just one row per product, no matter how many boxes or quantities of it there are).
- one row in box_product for A, 2 rows in box_product for B, and 3 rows in box_product for C (so 6 rows in the associative entity total).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write this. It was very helpful.